# Database of a Cross platform

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I am new to this platform & community. I'd like to know could there be major issues and bugs when it comes to creating a single database (with, or without the use of SSO) when it comes to scaling or speed.
Is it better to work with SSO, and have the current databases working in parallel, or is it better to deploy the data from those DB's into a new one, and stoping the old databases?

Both are RDB written in SQL. One is gathering the data for 2 web pages, part of a platform and the second DB is gathering the data from a mobile app.
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: The answer to this question may help you out.  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11670/pros-cons-using-multiple-databases-vs-using-single-database.  The same argument applies to scaling the databases.  If your applications share a database then they share resources and you have no easy way to throttle one or speed up just one.

Comment: You appear to be using Microsoft SQL Sever. A version might be useful to allow us to help you!

Comment: Using different databases on an instance will not improve performance.  If improving IO performance is what is intended, using different file groups on separate physical hardware will improve that.  Separating the DB's will only increase complexity in maintenance with little or no advantage I can see.